# デコレータのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3

下の画像のようなTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callableのようなエラーが出ます。
これはどういうことなんでしょうか？
いまいちデコレータについて使い方などピンときていません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` 関数の最後の `return` のインデントが間違っています。
1つ減らして、`def new_func(*argc, **kwargs):` の行と同じレベルのインデントであるべきです。

以下、Python 3.6.0 での実行例です。

```
>>> def test(func):
...     def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
...         print('start')
...         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
...         print('end')
...         return result
...     return new_func
... 
>>> @test
... def greething():
...     print('Greething')
... 
>>> greething()
start
Greething
end
>>>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。初歩的なミスでお恥ずかしいです。助かりました。